# iOS Push Notification for Enterprise Distribution App

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile

I have my push notification that works on development build. But when I build it using enterprise distribution it does not work at all.

Tried solution:
-created new provisioning profile with enabled push notification service

Comment: Which gateway are you using when sending push notifications to enterprise distribution? Make sure it's `gateway.push.apple.com 2195`. `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195` will not work.

Comment: @Eeshwar I am using the push notification service of Cloudmine.